# Is there an ESLint rule that limits the number of return statements?

Tags: eslint

The rule I'm looking for is(the name is provisional.):

This rule limits the number of return statements in a function.
(The example is ugly, but I expect the following behavior.)

```js
// "max-return-statement-per-function": ["error", 4]

// incorrect
function Foo(str) {
  if (str === "a") {
    return "a";
  } else if (str === "b") {
    return "b";
  } else if (str === "c") {
    return "c";
  } else if (str === "d") {
    return "d";
  } else {
    return "others";
  }
}

// correct
function Foo(str) {
  if (str === "a") {
    return "a";
  } else if (str === "b") {
    return "b";
  } else if (str === "c") {
    return "c";
  } else {
    return "others";
  }
}
```

Comment: what if your code simply needs that many `return` statements, for example because of precondition checks/early returns? that's a cumbersome rule.

Comment: Exactly...
The reason why I think this rule is necessary is that I am trying to reproduce [Codeclimate's default checks](https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/maintainability#checks) in ESLint. The checks include a rule called "return statements." It watches the number of return statements and issues a warning if the threshold is exceeded. I thought maybe a function with many return statements is not a good idea, but I guess not?